# как отрендерить массив во vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

как отрендерить массив вида:

[     {         firstName: "Vova",         lastName: "Uukina"         position: " Manager"     },     {         firstName: "Oleg",         lastName: "Turlevich"         position: "Manager"     },     {         firstName: "Nika",         lastName: "Arkadieva"         position: "Student"     }]

Comment: мне не ясна суть вопроса, отрендерить во что или куда, в список ?

Comment: Да нужно в список

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимально воспроизводимый пример демонстрирующий перебор значений из списка.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  list: [
   { firstName: "Vova", lastName: "Uukina", position: "Manager" },
   { firstName: "Oleg", lastName: "Turlevich", position: "Manager" },
   { firstName: "Nika", lastName: "Arkadieva", position: "Student" }
  ]
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <ul>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
   <h4>{{ item.firstName }} {{ item.lastName }} </h4>
   <p>{{ item.position }}</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**upd**: У вас в массиве после `lastName` пропущена запятая.

Comment: Cпасибо! Зароботало.